# Is function holomorphic for all complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

pls for help/check.

I have a function: $f(z)=3e^{i(z)}$. Is this function holomorhics for all complex numbers?

$f(x+iy)=3e^{i(x+iy)}=3e^{-y}\cos (x)+i3e^{-y}\sin (x)$

so $Re=3e^{-y}\cos (x)$ and $Im=3e^{-y}\sin (x)$

By the Cauchy-Riemann equations

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=3e^{-y}cos(x)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=3e^{-y}sin(x)=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$

And its not true. So this function is not holomorphic for all complex numbers. 
Is this correct??

Comment: Where does the $3$ come from?

Comment: Sorry, mistake at task. Now is updated.

Comment: Hint: try to prove that any composition of holomorphic functions is also holomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your calculations. You've miscalculated all the partial derivatives. With $u = 3e^{-y}\cos x$ and $v = 3e^{-y}\sin x$, we have $u_x = -3e^{-y}\sin x = v_y$ and $u_y = -3e^{-y}\cos x = -v_x$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied for all $z = x + iy$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Poorly I understood method of C-R. I compared the two different conditions of C-R. And I not derivate it. 
Now I understand.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to check your computations:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = e^{-y}(-\sin x)$$ $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = (-1)e^{-y}(\sin x)$$ $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = (-1)e^{-y}\cos x$$ $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = e^{-y}\cos x$$